# ajax: how to fetch data from database to html?

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, ajax

This application is developed with node, bootstrap, knex.
I need to fetch data from my mysql database "movedb" from the table Tab_Clienti(IDCliente, Cliente) to an html page called workspace.html , i'd like to use only javascript without php, and i need to put the fetched data into a `<select>` as a `<option>`

this is my knexfile.js:

```
module.exports = {
  client: 'mysql',
  connection: {
    user: 'root',
    password: '',
    database: 'movedb'
  }
}
```

and this is what i have in app.js:

```
function post (path, data) {
  return window.fetch(path, {
    method: 'POST',
    headers: {
      'Accept': 'application/json',
      'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    },
    body: JSON.stringify(data)
  })
}
```

I'm still learning develop web applications, so i apologize if there are some big mistakes. Thx for the support, if you have any questions or info to ask just ask me.

Comment: node.js is what you're using instead of PHP, and you need a way to serve pages (or JSON) via HTTP. People commonly use [express](http://expressjs.com/) for that. Try creating a basic webserver first, before adding knex.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like Chris G mentioned you need a way to serve page via HTTP. If you use express for this you can do something like this:

app.js

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var request = require('request');

var results = "some data";

app.get('/', function(req, res){
    res.render('index', {results : results});
})


app.listen(3000, 'localhost', function(){
    console.log("Server is running");
});
```

index.ejs

```
<script>console.log(<%- JSON.stringify(results) %>);</script>
```